# Filtering users from sharepoint 2013 search

Tags: search, search-results

I'm currently using the out of the box sharepoint 2013 search web part. However, I need to remove two users from the result list. So if people search for these users, nothing will appear.

Originally I just thought I would have to edit the search query, however, this has become problematic. After a bit of research, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

My query looks something like...

```
{searchboxquery} -Title:John Smith -Title:Jane Doe
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to make it so that the result list does not contain anything with the title of 'John Smith' or 'Jane Doe'. However, this does not work. Could someone steer me in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `Change Query Builder` for your purpose.

You may specify something like `xyz <> "Amit"` i.e. to say if xyz is equal to 'Amit' the result should not be included in the search results.

```
{searchboxquery}  Title<>Amit
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could do this, as a user all I need to do is stand up a People Search web part and I'll be able to find them myself. The right way to resolve this is to remove their User Profile and then recrawl the profiles.